# Multiple queries in one request

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, pg-promise

I'm trying to add new users to the database and have the id automatically iterated. The way I'm trying to do this is run a query first to check the total number of rows and then adding 1 to it to assign as the ID of the user I want to add.

**One of the problems I'm having is that in the first query the assignment of newUser.id is block scoped, and I cant access that value outside of it. The id for newUser stays at null, or undefined depending on how I move things around**

```
/add user to DB
router.post("/", (req, res) => {

var newID;

const newUser = {
    id: null,
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    active: true
};

 db.result("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users")
    .then(data => {
        newID = parseInt(data.rows[0].count) + 1;
        newUser.id = newID;

     //IF I CONSOLE.LOG(newUser) here then the value for id is 14

    });

    //IF I CONSOLE.LOG(newUser) here then the value for id is NULL

  db.none(
    "INSERT INTO users(id, name, email, active) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)",
    [newUser.id, newUser.name, newUser.email, newUser.active]
  )
    .then(data => {
      res.status(200).json({ msg: "new user was added" });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log("ERROR", error);
    });
```

Comment: Why not simply use a `serial` type, or an `identity` column in postgres? Then you don't need to make multiple db requests at all.

Comment: Hmm, I tried that, but I get this error:

`ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(12) already exists.
SQL state: 23505`

Comment: Okay so if I keep on doing it, eventually, the ID works it way up to the empty row. Why is it not starting at the free one at the start?

Comment: If you use a sequence, you need to leave the `id` column out of the `INSERT` statement so that it uses the generated value as the default

Comment: Or probably you created the sequence when you already had data in the table, but still had it start at 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the assignment of newUser.id is block scoped, and I cant access that value outside of it.

You will need to use promise chaining for that:

```
db.result("SELECT …")
.then(data => {
    newUser.id = parseInt(data.rows[0].count) + 1;
    return db.none("INSERT …", newUser);
}).then(data => {
    res.status(200).json({ msg: "new user was added" });
}, error => {
    console.log("ERROR", error);
});
```

> I'm trying to add new users to the database and have the id automatically iterated

Don't make two queries to achieve that. Use an [identity column](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-identity-column/) or [sequence](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-serial/) in the database for that.

Or at least join the two queries into a single statement to run at once:

```
db.none(
  "INSERT INTO users(id, name, email, active) VALUES ((SELECT COUNT(*)+1 FROM users), $1, $2, $3)",
  [newUser.name, newUser.email, newUser.active]
)
.then(data => {
  res.status(200).json({ msg: "new user was added" });
}, error => {
  console.log("ERROR", error);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using more than one query at a time, you should use a task:

```js
await db.task('add-new-user', async t => {
    const count = await t.one('SELECT count(*) FROM users', [], a => +a.count);
    newUser.id = count + 1;
    return t.none('INSERT INTO users(${this:name}) VALUES(${this:csv})', newUser);
});
```

P.S. You should use type `serial` instead, and then you can avoid all this.

Comment: Thank you, yes, definitely a better solution is to use serial.